# Vector addition in cuda

Tags: cuda

I am trying to learn cuda programming and when I tried to execute vector addition program from this tutorial [here](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/CUDA/training/GTC_Express_Sarah_Tariq_June2011.pdf), it's not working as expected, no error is thrown, but the answer isn't correct.

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<stdlib.h> 

#define N 20 

__global__ void add(int *a, int *b, int *c){ 
        c[blockIdx.x] = a[blockIdx.x] + b[blockIdx.x]; 
} 
int main(void) { 
        int *a, *b, *c; // host copies of a, b, c 
        int *d_a, *d_b, *d_c; // device copies of a, b, c 
        int size = N * sizeof(int), i; 
        // Alloc space for device copies of a, b, c 
        cudaMalloc((void **)&d_a, size); 
        cudaMalloc((void **)&d_b, size); 
        cudaMalloc((void **)&d_c, size); 
        // Alloc space for host copies of a, b, c and setup input values 
        a = (int *)malloc(size);  
        b = (int *)malloc(size); 
        c = (int *)malloc(size); 
        for(i = 0; i< N ; i++){ 
                a[i] = rand() % 100; 
                b[i] = rand() % 50; 
        } 
        // Copy inputs to device 
        cudaMemcpy(d_a, a, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice); 
        cudaMemcpy(d_b, b, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice); 
        // Launch add() kernel on GPU with N blocks 
        add<<<N,1>>>(d_a, d_b, d_c); 

        cudaDeviceSynchronize(); 
        // Copy result back to host 
        cudaMemcpy(c, d_c, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost); 
        // Cleanup 

        for(i = 0; i< N; i++) 
                printf("%d + %d = %d\n", a[i], b[i], c[i]); 
        free(a); free(b); free(c); 
        cudaFree(d_a); cudaFree(d_b); cudaFree(d_c); 
        return 0; 
}
```

The result is always shown as -1, I don't know why, can someone help me out here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used my GPU to compile and run the program and it is working as expected. You have to check the error codes returned by `cudaMalloc` and `cudaMemCpy` and make sure they are not returning any errors.

Comment: Thanks for checking it once. I tried to check the error codes returned by malloc and memcpy, but there aren't any. But after calling the add function I'm getting the error as `no kernel image is available for execution on the device
`, I tried googling it, but couldn't find proper solution. Thanks!

Comment: can you share with us how do you compile your program?

Comment: and what GPU and what CUDA version

Comment: GPU is nvidia GT 610, and CUDA is the latest version

Comment: @V.SubramaniRaju the GT610 is not supported in the latest cuda version

Comment: use cuda 8 instead

Comment: Where's the list of supported devices? And is there any alternate way to test out the code?

Comment: @V.SubramaniRaju The list of CUDA supported GPUs cards can be found on-line on the nvidia developer dedicated page https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus. If your card is not listed there, probably it is too newer or not supported at all. Take a look at your card model and corresponding cuda compute capability (last column). Starting from CUDA SDK 8.x the compute capability 2.x is not compiled by default (as deprecated). Use nvcc -arch=sm_XY where XY corresponds to major (X) and minor (Y) compute capability identifier without dot in between. Later SDK dropped support for compute capability 2.x